# Where should macros like HAVE_SYS_UIO_H be defined?

Tags: c

I need to include a header file which needs `HAVE_SYS_UIO_H` to be defined. My system do actually have `sys/uio.h`, but the macro isn't defined automatically. For the moment, I can define it before including the header, but this is obviously a bad idea.

What do I need to do to get `HAVE_SYS_UIO_H` (and other macros like it) to be defined correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have some logic in your makefile that checks for the presence of the header and adds -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H if so. Using automake may make this easier or prompt the user to provide the values (e.g. via make CONFIGURE).

Answer (score 3):

Usually things like "HAVE_SOMETHING" are defined in Makefiles generated by "./configure" script which actually makes test programs and tries to compile and run them to figure out whether a particular system has a particular thing or not.